# Auto update image to value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to auto update the image to the text of the input box.
Here is the index code:

```
<body>
<div id="registeer">

  <form method="post" action="javascript:login()">
    <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" /><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Wachtwoord" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Registeer">
  <form>
  <br>

  </div>
  <div id="registeer-avatar"></div>


<script src="registeer.js"></script>
```

And here is the registeer.js:

```
$("#registeer input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
var value = $(this).val();
var background = "url(https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user=" + value + "&action=std&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=b)";
$("#registeer-avatar").css("background", background);
});


$("#registeer input[type=text]").blur(function() {
if(!this.value) {
    $("#registeer-avatar").css("background", "url(https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user=ulk&action=std&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=b)");
}
});
```

So if you type in the first input for example 'hi', the image in registeer-avatar will be habbo....&user=hi, but it is not working.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, but you need to size the container:

```
  <div id="registeer-avatar"></div>
```

as it is now it has no "space" and when background is set, it does not show.

Try, for example, CSS:

```
#registeer-avatar {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```js
$("#registeer input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
var value = $(this).val();
var background = "url(https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user=" + value + "&action=std&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=b)";
$("#registeer-avatar").css("background-image", background);

    console.log(background);
    
});


$("#registeer input[type=text]").blur(function() {
if(!this.value) {
    $("#registeer-avatar").css("background", "url(https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user=ulk&action=std&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=b)");
}
});
```

```css
#registeer-avatar {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="registeer">

  <form method="post" action="javascript:login()">
    <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" /><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Wachtwoord" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Registeer">
  <form>
  <br>

  <div id="registeer-avatar"></div>
```

Comment: I changed it to <div id="registeer-avatar" style="width: 99px; height: 99px;"> </div> but it is still not working?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add the jquery, it is working now. thanks for helping!